# Linking FROM a mobile application

Tags: mobile, google-analytics

I am looking to find a way to tag a link from inside the app to a webpage. We have links in our mobile app that link to a page on our website. The links open in an in-app browser. I want to be able to use UTM tagging to track when someone taps the link to the website link. Is that possible? I'm not talking about deep linking into the app, I'm talking about linking from inside the app.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add UTM parameters in querystring at links pointing to the website.

The site must obviously have the Google Analytics snippet to track source / medium.